# make: forcing a rule to be used

Tags: makefile

Typping `make` (Gnu Make) with the following `Makefile` (assuming files `foo.x` and `foo.y` are missing)

```
all: foo.z

foo.z: foo.x foo.y
  cat foo.x foo.y > foo.z
```

produce the error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.x', needed by `foo.z'.  Stop.
```

But this `Makefile`:

```
all: foo.z

%.z: %.x %.y
  cat %.x %.y > %.z
```

produce this error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.z', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

In the first case, the rule is applied, and a dependency if found to be missing.
In the second case, the rule is found to be not appropriate, and that is a rule that is missing.

I want to use the second `Makefile` (I have a lot a `*.z` object to be created), but with an error message like with the first `Makefile`. My `make` output is logged, and having the expanded name of the missing files will help debugging.

Is it possible? Maybe a way to force the rule to be used?

Of course I'm not catting file, this is just a example...

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not as part of your question.

Comment: Done. I think I wrote the answer as part of my question because at the time I did it there was a rule that prevent me to answer my question during a period...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found:

```
all: foo.z

OBJ=foo.z

$(OBJ): %.z: %.x %.y
   cat %.x %.y > %.z
```

One need [Static Pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). Amazing make...